# Ms Word Macro - disable 'Change font' button

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I disable specific button in ms-word using macro? I've searched a lot in google, but can't find any example. I don't know how to identify button name or action that button triggers.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to disable specific buttons of built in ribbons.

Comment: Thanks @Peh. So maybe can I override action that changes font? I've already override action that pastes text ('EditPaste()'). Maybe you know how can I identify this action?

Comment: Don't think you can override that but you can build your own tab in the ribbon: This http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/20/make-new-ribbons-in-excel/ or this http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable "Change Font" buton in built in ribbon is impossioble.